# Positive definite and Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, positive-definite

Will a positive definite matrix always be diagonalizable, in such a way that we can only use ordinary eigenvectors?

Two other similar questions are:

$1.$ Will an $n \times n$ positive definite matrix  always have $n$ distinct eigenvalues?
$2.$Can any eigenvalue of a positive definite matrix (with multiplicity $m \gt 1$) be "missing" an eigenvector?

Assuming that these are indeed valid questions.

Comment: They' re not, $1$ not necessairly distinct, $2$ no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider, e.g., the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $A$ is positive definite, but not diagonalizable.

The same example answers questions 1. and 2.